# PHP, нужна помощь с bind_param

Tags: php, ооп, mysqli

Пытаюсь написать класс для sql query. Вот, попробовала написать такое:

```
class SQL {

public $connection;
public $query;

public function __construct() {
    $this->connection = mysqli_connect("localhost", "blabla", "arararar");
    mysqli_select_db($this->connection, "blabla");
}

public function select($rowName, $tableName, $rowNameCondition, $whereCondition) {

    if (strlen($rowNameCondition) == 0 && strlen($whereCondition) == 0) {

        $this->query = $this->connection->prepare("select ? from ?");
        $this->query->bind_param('ss', $rowName, $tableName);
        $this->query->execute();
        return $this->query->fetchAll();

    } else {

        $this->query = $this->connection->prepare("select ? from ? where ? = ?");
        $this->query->bind_param('sssi', $rowName, $tableName, $rowNameCondition, $whereCondition);
        $this->query->execute();
        return $this->query->fetchAll();

    }

    //return mysqli_query($this->connection, $this->query);
}
```

}

Вызываю и использую таким образом:

```
$result = $SQLobject->select("city", "telegramUsers", "chatID", $chatID);

    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {

        if ($row["city"] !== "none") {

            $cityID = $row["city"];

        } elseif ($row["city"] == "none") {

            $telegramAPIobject->sendMessage("Будь ласка, виберіть місто", $chatID);
        }
    }
```

Пожалуйста-пожалуйста, подскажите что я делаю не так

Comment: Переменные только подставить можно, название полей и таблиц придется ставить прямо в запрос. Чтобы не было проблем их следует проверять по белым списках разрешенных имен!

Comment: в добавок, вы уже в `select` делаете `fetchAll` и вероятно возвращаете уже массив результатов. Дак почему же вы вызывюащем коде у вас цикл с `mysqli_fetch_assoc`? у вас в `$result` там готовые данные лежат

Comment: +формат передачи данных в `select` кривой. у вас два последних параметра это имя и значение поля для генерации `where`, поскольку вы их подставляете  как `? = ?` значит, что вы сможете написать условие только на одно поле. А если надо два поля, то что делать? Передавайте массив, где ключи - названия полей ,а значения - значения параметра. также ключи можно использовать для именованных плейсхолдеров.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы хотите написать конструктор SQL-запросов. Удобно разделить само конструирование и использование полученного запроса. Для начала соберём запрос с плэйсхолдерами (без значений, но с указателями куда надо подставить значения), который можно будет передать в mysqli_prepare.

Для подстановки имён таблиц и столбцов в строку запроса потребуется функция экранирования. В MySQL эти имена могут содержать самые разные символы и ограничиваются с помощью символа обратного апострофа. Имена могут содержать и обратный апостроф, тогда его нужно экранировать ещё одним апострофом (в [документации MySQL](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/identifiers.html) можно почитать об этом подробнее), я надеюсь из кода станет понятно о чём речь:

```
class SQL {

    private static function quote($str) {
        return '`'.strtr($str, array('`' => '``')).'`';
    }

}
```

Теперь добавим простой метод для создания select-запроса:

```
public static function select($rowName, $tableName, $rowNameCondition = null) {
    $sql = 'select ' . self::quote($rowName);
    $sql .= ' from ' . self::quote($tableName);

    if ($rowNameCondition) {
        $sql .= ' where ' . self::quote($rowNameCondition) . ' = ?';
    }

    return $sql;
}
```

Теперь вызывая `SQL::select('city', 'telegramUsers', 'chatID');`, мы получим строку:

```
select `city` from `telegramUsers` where `chatID` = ?
```

Осталось написать код, который передаст запрос в базу данных:

```
class DB {

    private $connection;

    public function __construct($host, $username, $password, $defaultDb) {
        $this->connection = new mysqli($host, $username, $passwordm $defaultDb);
    }

    public function select($rowName, $tableName, $rowNameCondition = null, $whereCondition = null) {
        $sql = SQL::select($rowName, $tableName, $rowNameCondition);
        $query = $this->connection->prepare($sql);
        if ($rowNameCondition) {
            $query->bind_param('s', $whereCondition);
        }
        $query->execute();
        $result = $query->get_result();

        return $result->fetch_all(); // доступно только с расширением mysqlnd
    }

}
```

Используйте!

```
$db = new DB("localhost", "blabla", "arararar", "blabla");
$row = $db->select("city", "telegramUsers", "chatID", $chatID);
foreach ($rows as $row) {
    var_dump($row);
}
```

Развивая этот код обратите внимание вот на что:

1. Я использовал параметры конструктора DB, чтобы не зашивать их внутрь. Это позволит использовать класс для разных баз.
2. Я не использовал `$this->query`, потому что переменная не нужна за пределами метода.
3. Я использовал значения по умолчанию, что бывает удобно.
4. Вы упустили, что метод `fetch_all` -- метод класса `mysqli_result`.
5. Обратите внимание, что существуют готовые решения для вашей задачи, возможно вам следует использовать их. Если вы не знакомы с менеджером зависимостей [composer](https://getcomposer.org/), обязательно познакомьтесь.